# Unable to import OpenCV in Python project file, but works in Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm facing an issue with importing OpenCV in my Python project file. Strangely, I can import it without any problems in Python's IDLE, but when I try to import it in my project file, it fails. I've tried several solutions, but none seem to work. Here are the details of my setup and what I've tried so far:

**Environment:**

- Python version: 3.10.4
- Operating system: windows

**Problem:**

In my project file (file.py), I have the following import statement:

```
import cv2
```

When I run this script, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst'
```

**What I've tried:**

I verified that I'm using the same Python version in both Python IDLE and my project file.
I checked if there are any name conflicts with my project file or directories.
I made sure that the OpenCV package is installed in my Python environment using pip install opencv-python.
I activated the same virtual environment (if applicable) in both IDLE and my project file.
I checked that the OpenCV package (cv2 directory) exists within my Python installation's site-packages directory.
**Additional Information:**

If I try to import other Python packages in my project file, they work fine.
I'm using Python IDLE, and the project file is a separate Python script (file.py).
I'm still unable to figure out why OpenCV imports correctly in Python IDLE but not in my project file. Any suggestions or insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/just here.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 72, in bootstrap
    save_sys_path = copy.copy(sys.path)
TypeError: copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst'
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.